# Two integrals that should not be equal

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier and persisting through 14.0**

*CASE:4539809*

---

I think there is a bug here:

```
In[1]:= Integrate[Abs[Cos[x^4]], {x, 0, Infinity}]

Out[1]= Cos[\[Pi]/8] Gamma[5/4]

In[2]:= Integrate[Cos[x^4], {x, 0, Infinity}]

Out[2]= Cos[\[Pi]/8] Gamma[5/4]
```

Maple finds the same answer (albeit not as simplified) for the latter, and no answer for the former. Obviously, the values can't be equal, so I'm rather confident there is indeed a bug.

It might be worth noting that with `RealAbs`, Mathematica leaves the integral unevaluated.

*Mathematica 12.1.0 on Windows 10*

Comment: "Obviously, the values can't be equal" - how so?

Comment: @J.M. The difference of two positive numbers can't equal their sum. (the two positive numbers being here the integral of the positive part and the integral of the negative part of the integrand).

Comment: Same here on MMA 12.0.0.0 (Linux); the first one takes much longer though.

Comment: @anderstood Yes, I noted that too.

Comment: @anders, there is something indeed that is anomalous, but I wanted Jean-Claude to specify what is "obvious". Also, it is possible for a nonnegative oscillatory function to have a finite-valued infinite integral, if the decay rate is suitable, e.g. `Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Cos[x]], {x, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: @J.M. Yes I deleted my comment when I realized that. Thanks for the example

Comment: Please do report it to Wolfram.

Comment: @J.M. My comment is partly wrong: that's supposing $\cos(x^4)$ is absolutely integrable, but I'm not sure it is (but the problem remains anyway).

Comment: Yes, something fishy is going on. Manually splitting and evaluating the integral seems to argue against convergence: `Integrate[Cos[x^4], {x, 0, (π/2)^(1/4)}] + NSum[(-1)^k Evaluate[Assuming[k ≥ 1, Integrate[Cos[x^4], {x, π^(1/4) (k - 1/2)^(1/4), π^(1/4) (k + 1/2)^(1/4)}]]], {k, 1, ∞}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Wolfram support CASE:4539809

Comment: I believe the first integral is divergent.  Make the substitution $t=x^4$ and you get $\int|\cos t|/ (4t^{3/4}) \,dt$, which integrating up to $t=(N+{1\over2})\pi$, is greater than $\sum_{k=1}^N \pi^{-3/4}(k+{1\over2})^{-3/4}$ which diverges.

Comment: While using `RealAbs` does not evaluate, using the equivalent `Integrate[Sqrt[Cos[x^4]^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]` gives the erroneous result. v12.1

Comment: The same issue with `Integrate[Abs[Cos[x^5]], {x, 0, Infinity}]` which performs `-(1/25) Sqrt[2 (5 + Sqrt[5])] Gamma[-(4/5)]`, whereas the integral is divergent. The same issue with `Integrate[Abs[Cos[x^6]], {x, 0, Infinity}]` too.

Comment: In 13.2 on Windows 10 `Integrate[Abs[Cos[x^4]], {x, 0, Infinity}]` returns the input.

Comment: It should be added the above result  depends on a session and is rare.